# Finding Spearman's rank correlation coefficient with sum of ranks

Tags: spearman-rho

Xi and Yi are the ranks for the ith student such that Xi+Yi=21(I=1,...,20). Then the Spearman rank correlation coefficient between X and Y is?
How do I even proceed with this. Coefficient requires difference of ranks??

Comment: This is unanswerable because the information is insufficient or unclear.  Are you claiming that for *all* students the sum of the ranks is $21$ or just for *one particular* student?  If it's the former, then this must be a textbook question intended to probe your understanding, in which case please read about [how we answer such questions here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Its from a previous year question paper that I am solving, and I'm not getting the question even.

Comment: Start by drawing a scatterplot of the ranks.  What does it suggest?  (To save time and effort, replace the "21" in the question by a smaller value such as "4".)

Comment: I did for 20 only, turns out they are highly negatively correlated! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can be more specific: you can determine exactly what the correlation coefficient is ;-).